# Install xdebug on specific php version

Tags: php, xdebug, pecl

I'm trying to install xdebug.

I've already seen some issues about it (like this one : [Installing xdebug with PHP 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457856/installing-xdebug-with-php-5-5) ) but it seems outdated and not corresponding to my issue).

When I try

`sudo pecl install xdebug`

I'm getting the following error

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>
> downloading xdebug-2.8.0.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download xdebug-2.8.0.tgz (238,122 bytes)
>   .................................................done: 238,122 bytes
>
> 69 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>   sh: 1: phpize: not found
>   ERROR: `phpize' failed

It seems that means phpize isn't installed in my php version

`php -v`

> PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2019 11:49:39) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

So, some topics seems to tell me to change my php version to download a version with phpsize included. But I was more looking for a way to add phpsize to my current php version but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: What os are you used?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize

Comment: @Dmitry Ubuntu like shown in the php -v. Ihave already seen that topic but that means I have to install a new php version then ?

Comment: I think you need install php7.x-dev version also.

Comment: Example: sudo apt install php7.x-dev. And then sudo pecl install xdebug.

Comment: Well I did it then. But that means I have to change my default php version now no ? I will still be using PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.19.04.1 and not php7.2-dev

Comment: Try install xdebug.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes the install worked but I have to enable it. And to enable it I need to know what php.ini file I have to modify I guess.

Comment: I think php7.2 not dev

Comment: Ok looks weird in fact I only have a php 7.2 I suspect the 7.2-dev to be only some kind of extension inside the 7.2. Problem solved then. I let you post it as an answer to mark as resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Ubuntu first you need install php dev version:

```
sudo apt install php7.x-dev
```

And then:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Comment: Show php -v  output

Comment: Didn't change from the one in question

Comment: Oh wait I have modified the apache/php.ini I might should have modified the cli/php.ini instead maybe ?

Comment: And indeed It was the wrong php.ini file I modified.

Comment: Check it cli/php.ini.

Comment: Yes it was the cli one I needed to modify.

Comment: I hope it's help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with xdebug version too.
I had to install an specific version for php7.1 using PECL,

I don't really know if your question is already solved but let me share  you this webpage, it's the compatibility graph to know wich version works with an specific php versions:

https://xdebug.org/docs/compat

As far as I know if you want to install the latest xdebug version you can use the repo, but if you need an old version you'll be forced to install it using PECL.

Hope you find this answer usefull!