# Php8.1-dev not install phpize in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to connect the oracle database with Laravel. But when we trying run this command "pecl install oci8". It will throw an error. I am using ubuntu 18.4 and PHP version 8.1. How to install phpize.

```
root@linux:~# pecl install oci8
    downloading oci8-3.2.1.tgz ...
    Starting to download oci8-3.2.1.tgz (190,781 bytes)
    .........................................done: 190,781 bytes
    13 source files, building
    running: phpize
    sh: 1: phpize: not found
    ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Comment: How about installing PHP dev first?

Comment: sudo apt install php8.1-dev php8.1-pear build-essential libaio

Comment: How about `dpkg -S /usr/bin/phpize` ? Guess you might need the default PHP package, too.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.4. Any idea to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install xdebug on specific php version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090812/install-xdebug-on-specific-php-version)

Comment: Search for the error message online, that usually turns up some results.

Comment: I had similar issue this working for me https://stackoverflow.com/q/72530556/2531629

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Alpine with PHP8.1, I solved it by adding:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/phpize81 /usr/bin/phpize
ln -s /usr/bin/pecl81 /usr/bin/pecl
```

to the docker file, for unknown reason the phpize and pecl are missing by php81 installaion.