# Trying to install the phpize extension on the Ubuntu php8.1

Tags: php, php-8.1

I am trying to install the phpize on Ubuntu 20.04 PHP 8.1

I tried following commands but no luck

1. `sudo apt-get install php8.0-dev`

```
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-dev'
```

2. `sudo apt-get install php-dev`

```
 php-dev : Depends: php7.4-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

3. `sudo apt-get install php8.1-dev`

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-dev'
```

Comment: Try using this command

apt-get install php8.1-dev

Comment: E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-dev'

Comment: sudo apt update && apt install -y software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt update

and then try

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you post it as an answer. So i will accept the answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y software-properties-common 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php 
sudo apt update
```

and then try

Comment: Can you explain what each of these commands do and why they are needed to fix the problem in the question?

Comment: It will get the latest headers from the php repository and will install on the local machine for the libraries that are required

Answer (score 0):

You might find the following also appropriate:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# To add this repository please do:

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    SUDO=sudo
fi

${SUDO} apt-get update
${SUDO} apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
${SUDO} curl -sSLo /usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
${SUDO} sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
${SUDO} apt-get update
```

Source: https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

---

For example, a Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable

# ...

# PHP 8.1
# --------------------------------
# Related: https://packages.sury.org/php/README.txt

RUN \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get full-upgrade && \
        apt-get clean;

RUN \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND='noninteractive' \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y -- \
            apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl && \
        curl -sSLo '/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg' 'https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg' && \
        printf -- '%s\n' "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $( lsb_release -sc; ) main" > '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list' && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
            php8.1-fpm php8.1-bcmath php8.1-curl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-pdo php8.1-mysql php8.1-xml && \
        apt-get clean;

# ...

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "php-fpm8.1" ]
```

---

Just in case, currently, the main difference between relatively common [Debian](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian) and [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) Linux [PHP extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/extensions.php) installations is that the latter [builds](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) extensions (i.e. make, docker-php-extension-installer) and the former - uses pre-compiled binaries (e.g. [Bullseye/amd64](https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/bullseye/main/binary-amd64)).

Alpine versions are currently mostly used in the [official PHP Docker registry](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), yet the above [PPA for PHP (5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0 and 8.1)](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org) ([ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)) mostly by [Ondřej Surý](https://github.com/sponsors/oerdnj) is quite known and trusted.

> I am a Debian Developer since year 2000, and I have been packaging PHP for Debian since PHP 5. That means the official packages in Debian and Ubuntu are either my work or they are based on my work. The PHP packages in my Ubuntu PPA and Debian DPA matches the official packages in Debian. Basically I am saying that you can’t get any closer than that.

Source: https://deb.sury.org

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: php -m | grep mbstring
Step 2: sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring
Step 3: php.ini -> extension=mbstring

$word= "merhaba";
$firstchar= substr($word, 0, 1);
echo $firstchar; // "m"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does that mbstring extension relate to the original problem?